# How to insert a query result into a column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

ok so I do this mysql command:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Familenaam,1,4),SUBSTRING(Voornaam,1,4)) AS `Login` FROM tblusers
```

This gives me the result for johny cowbell -_> johncowb (=loginname) but this is in a query.

I want that result in my table tblusers in the column "Login".
How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`INSERT INTO .. SELECT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) like so:

```
INSERT INTO tblusers(login)
SELECT 
  CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Familenaam, 1 ,4), SUBSTRING(Voornaam,1,4)) 
FROM tblusers
```

If you want to update, you can do this:

```
UPDATE tblusers t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT 
     userid,
     CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Familenaam, 1 ,4), SUBSTRING(Voornaam,1,4)) login
   FROM tblusers
) t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
SET t1.login = t2.login
```

Comment: Thanks! But I actually need an UPDATE of the current users, do you know how to do that?

Comment: @JohnSmittheeerrs - Yes, see my edit. Note that, I used `userid` as the condition for the join, you can use other columns as well based on the table structure.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm going to give it a whirl :p
EDIT: It works! Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

You would do:

```
INSERT INTO tblusers (Login)
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Familenaam,1,4),SUBSTRING(Voornaam,1,4)) AS `Login` FROM tblusers;
```

This is essentially saying "insert the result of my 'SELECT' query into the 'login' column of table 'tblusers'.

Comment: Thanks! But I actually need an UPDATE of the current users, do you know how to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You want to update the current user's login name?

Comment: The users at this moment have no loginname yet. So next to the First name and last name column there has to come a login column with the loginame. (the columon is already made but the value is still empty)